# cannot get size of std::vector<char> after reading binary file

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

For context, I serialized a FlatBuffers object, saved it to a binary file `data.bin`, and now want to read it back.

Following the example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54446430/3927314, I have

```
std::ifstream infile("data.bin", std::ios_base::binary);
std::vector<char> buffer(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
    );
std::cout << buffer.size() << std::endl; // error
```

On the last line, why do I get this error when compiling? I was confused because I thought `size()` is a member function that can be called on all `std::vector` objects.

`error: request for member 'size' in 'buffer', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<char>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)())'`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21802936/4641116

Comment: You're parse of `buffer` isn't what you think it is. The greedy parse puts `buffer` as a function (believe it or not).  Surround either/both of its ctor arguments with parens, or use `std::vector<char<> buffer {...};` universal initialization (note the curlies; not parens, around the ctor argument list).

Comment: `auto buffer = std::vector<char>( ... )` will also fix it

Comment: This is most vexing